# writing to file given by path in environment variable

Tags: bash, variables, environment

I have a file given by path in environment variable. I need to write into   file for example something like this (date):

```
export tea=`~/documents/texts/file`
$tea<date
```

shortly i don't know how to work with the file if it is given by path like this, can you give me some examples?
(ps sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first line is attempting to run `~/documents/texts/file` as a program and will capture its output in the `tea` variable.

The contents of the `tea` variable will then be run as a command with that commands input being read from a file named `date`.

I don't believe any of that is likely what you intended.

Your first line should likely be

```
export tea=~/documents/texts/file
```

To write the output of the `date` command to that file you want to use

```
date >"$tea"
```

Comment: trying to write actual date to file

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. I have one question-why should there be at the second line quotes...? It works even without them.

Comment: If the filename had spaces or other shell special characters it wouldn't work without quotes. The general rule in the shell is always quote your variable expansions. Compare what happens in an empty directory if you run `f="one two"; touch $f; ls -l` with what happens if you run `f="one two"; touch "$f"; ls -l` for a simple example.